# How can I add a north arrow to a leaflet.js map?

Tags: dictionary, leaflet

Is there an easy way to add a north arrow to a leaflet.js map? I have searched a bit online but I cannot find much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a control that contains a div with your north arrow image:

```
var north = L.control({position: "bottomright"});
north.onAdd = function(map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create("div", "info legend");
    div.innerHTML = '<img src="your-north-arrow.png">';
    return div;
}
north.addTo(map);
```

See [Leaflet's control documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control) for more info on positioning and other options.