# Good way to draw a directional (arrowed) marker in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I need to create a custom `Marker` class in Leaflet: the marker must include a direction arrow. The arrow size should not depend on a zoom level. The direction should be editable (the arrow head should be draggable itself).

It was pretty easy to create a class and draft basic editing and events. And now...

1. I'm not sure what is the best way to draw it. At present, I'm adding a `Polyline` and changing its end coordinate every time a zoom changes. I believe there should be a way to "just draw a line in pixel coordinates", but the abstractions there are too deep to dive recklessly - things like `L.Browser.ie` are pretty scary. Can anyone please tell me, is there a better way to draw an arrow, or should I go with `Polyline`?
2. On a second stage, the arrow head needs to be draggable. I apparently hooked the necessary events, but WHAT object should be dragged here? Should an arrow head be an `Icon` itself (that's what I do now)? Or is there a layer/extension that can apply dragging without creating a map object?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `.png` images for icons. Make a list of different variation of arrows.

Comment: I thought of [mapbox rotating marker](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/rotating-controlling-marker/) as an arrow head. It uses `L.DomUtil.TRANSFORM` or `progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix` rotation. Though, I'd be fine with just a 3-line arrow, without icons.

Comment: Maybe a zoom-independent arrow head could be a `Control`, like in "north arrow": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325460/how-can-i-add-a-north-arrow-to-a-leaflet-js-map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using plain `.png` icons.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qJbgm

Comment: Thanks a lot. I might try "rotating marker" example too, it's apparently accurate for arbitrary angle.

Answer (score 0):

Use plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-canvas-markers 
You can create a direction arrow by simply pointing to the previous waypoint! Or set custom rotate.